# AutoResetEvent with multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have an multiuser application with a SQL back end.  Certain key data needs to be kept current between users, so I have a background refresh on those collection classes.  My current refresh code is as follows.

```
public virtual bool Refresh()
{
    if (SetRefreshThread() == RefreshLockStatus.AlreadyRefreshing) {
        DebugLogging("Checking for refresh thread lock", ClassDebugLevel.CollectionRefresh);
        if (RefreshLock.WaitOne(5000) == false) {
            DebugLogging("Refresh in already in progress on another thread.  Aborting refresh");
            return false;
        } else {
            DebugLogging("Finished refreshing on other thread so not refreshing again");
            return true;
        }
    }
    DebugLogging("Refresh Starting");
    //Refresh code here
    DebugLogging("Finished refreshing");
    ClearRefreshThread();
    return true;
}
protected RefreshLockStatus SetRefreshThread()
{
    lock (RefreshSyncLock) {
        if (_RefreshThread != null) {
            return RefreshLockStatus.AlreadyRefreshing;
        }
        _RefreshThread = Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;
        RefreshLock.Reset();
        return RefreshLockStatus.Allowed;
    }
}
protected void ClearRefreshThread()
{
    lock (RefreshSyncLock) {
        _RefreshThread = null;
        RefreshLock.Set();
    }
}
private readonly Threading.AutoResetEvent RefreshLock = new Threading.AutoResetEvent(true);
```

This works fine when called by a single thread, I get the log:

```
2017-07-06 07:13:55.272294 Thread #010 Collection1->Refresh Starting
2017-07-06 07:13:55.323755 Thread #010 Collection1->Finished refreshing
```

On two threads, I get also get the expected results:

```
2017-07-06 07:13:55.272294 Thread #010 Collection1->Refresh Starting
2017-07-06 07:13:55.272294 Thread #011 Collection1->Checking for refresh thread lock
2017-07-06 07:13:55.323755 Thread #010 Collection1->Finished refreshing
2017-07-06 07:13:55.325258 Thread #011 Collection1->Finished refreshing on other thread so not refreshing again
```

On three threads, the third thread times out rather than finishing when the first thread does

```
2017-07-06 07:13:55.272294 Thread #010 Collection1->Refresh Starting
2017-07-06 07:13:55.272294 Thread #011 Collection1->Checking for refresh thread lock
2017-07-06 07:13:55.272294 Thread #014 Collection1->Checking for refresh thread lock
2017-07-06 07:13:55.323755 Thread #010 Collection1->Finished refreshing
2017-07-06 07:13:55.325258 Thread #011 Collection1->Finished refreshing on other thread so not refreshing again
2017-07-06 07:14:00.872013 Thread #014 Collection1->Refresh in already in progress on another thread.  Aborting refresh
```

My goal is that if a refresh starts on one thread, and while it is executing, other threads want to refresh that same data they all wait for the first thread to finish, then all return true.  Is there a better synchronization object to accomplish what I want?

Comment: For what you're trying to do (locking a critical section so that only one thread may access it at a time), I think it would be better to use `Monitor.TryEnter` and `Monitor.Exit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when there are multiple threads paused at the same WaitOne method, the Set method will allow one of them to pass, but not all of them.

Since my goal was to just return as if the method had completed, I just needed to add another Set on the branch after the WaitOne.

```
public virtual bool Refresh()
{
    if (SetRefreshThread() == RefreshLockStatus.AlreadyRefreshing) {
        DebugLogging("Checking for refresh thread lock", ClassDebugLevel.CollectionRefresh);
        if (RefreshLock.WaitOne(5000) == false) {
            DebugLogging("Refresh in already in progress on another thread.  Aborting refresh");
            return false;
        } else {
            DebugLogging("Finished refreshing on other thread so not refreshing again");
            RefreshLock.Set //Let next thread that is waiting pass
            return true;
        }
    }
    DebugLogging("Refresh Starting");
    //Refresh code here
    DebugLogging("Finished refreshing");
    ClearRefreshThread();
    return true;
}
```

This gives me my desired log of

```
2017-07-07 06:35:28.115506 Thread #011 Collection1->Refresh Starting
2017-07-07 06:35:28.115506 Thread #014 Collection1->Checking for refresh thread lock
2017-07-07 06:35:28.115506 Thread #010 Collection1->Checking for refresh thread lock
2017-07-07 06:35:28.203229 Thread #011 Collection1->Finished refreshing
2017-07-07 06:35:28.204233 Thread #010 Collection1->Finished refreshing on other thread so not refreshing again
2017-07-07 06:35:28.204734 Thread #014 Collection1->Finished refreshing on other thread so not refreshing again
```